# How to subplot histogram using multiple columns with plotly?

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, histogram, subplot

So I have data that I transformed up to this point (pic below). How can I now subplot histograms that will show me the programming languages used per job? I tried with just 2 columns at first:

```
px.histogram(languages_job_title_grouped, x =['Python','SQL'], facet_col = 'Role', facet_col_wrap = 4,height = 1000)
```

But it didn't work - it plots histogram by job, but the bars are the same for every role (2nd picture below).
How can I do it the right way?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you include the sample of your dataframe as formatted text instead of an image (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples))? you can copy and paste the output from languages_job_title_grouped.head(10).to_dict() into your question – thank you!

Comment: @DerekO Sure, there you go:
{'Python': {'Business Analyst': 0.29906542056074764,
  'DBA/Database Engineer': 0.2465753424657534,
  'Data Analyst': 0.299390243902439,
  'Data Engineer': 0.291497975708502,
  'Data Scientist': 0.3303467903446822,
  'Not employed': 0.3525641025641026
 }}

Had to make it shorter to fit the comment size constraint; other keys like 'Python' will be ['SQL,'None/NA','R', 'Javascript','Java']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context of your question, it seems like you are looking for a bar plot instead.

I.e. If I understand correctly, you are starting from a dataframe equivalent to

[image: example_df]

and trying to plot
[image: bar_plot]

where the facets are the index, the x-axis is each column, and the bar heights are the values in the dataframe.

The code that generates this is:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[0.1, 0.3, 0.5], [0.2, 0.1, 0.8], [0.5, 0.3, 0.9]],
    columns=["a", "b", "c"],
    index=["index1", "index2", "index3"],
)

px.bar(
    df.melt(ignore_index=False).reset_index(),
    facet_col="index",
    x="variable",
    y="value",
    barmode="group",
)
```

The key being to reformat your DataFrame using `melt` before trying to plot with `plotly.express`.

Comment: That melt function is really cool, thanks for helping out!

Comment: Glad that worked for you! There are a lot of nice tricks to learn with pandas!